# How to grep for the first instance of a partial known string?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file with information:

```
<stuff:stuff id="1s23-abc" name="first" time="12:00" id="4s5abc67" name="first" time="12:30" > <more:stuff id="1s23-abc" name="first" time="12:00" id="4s5abc67" name="first" time="12:30" >
```

How can I grep for the first instance of *id="1s23-abc"*? I basically want to grep for something that starts with *id="* but ends with  quote followed by a space. Any text can appear before and after the text: *id="1s23-abc"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<stuff:stuff id="1s23-abc" name="first" time="12:00" id="4s5abc67" name="first" time="12:30" > <more:stuff id="1s23-abc" name="first" time="12:00" id="4s5abc67" name="first" time="12:30" >' | grep -Eo 'id=\"(\S*)\"' | head -1
```

Version for tired eyes:

```
string='<stuff:stuff id="1s23-abc" name="first" time="12:00" id="4s5abc67" name="first" time="12:30" > <more:stuff id="1s23-abc" name="first" time="12:00" id="4s5abc67" name="first" time="12:30" >'
echo $string | grep -Eo 'id=\"(\S*)\"' | head -1
```

Comment: I updated the quest where any text can appear before or after. The file does not have a line that starts with id